# AWS Options to transfer a file out

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, aws-lambda

Just wondering what would be some options to transfer (sftp) a file on an S3 bucket out to an external (in this case a file server on an external datacentre)?

Answer (score 0):

Either external data center need to pull the file or you need to download the file manually and upload it.

Comment: Cant I use a lambda function to push files out of AWS to the target, if the target has a public IP?

Comment: Yes, it is doable. You can write batch file and schedule it with cron as well.

Answer (score 0):

AWS offers a service called **Storage Gateway** this can be used to sync files between S3 and an on premise machine in different ways (cache, full copy i believe). The on premise machine can then do whatever it wants with the file(s).

Another (i.m.o. more hacked together option) is to create a lambda that copies/moves files from your S3 to an on premise by means of any protocol you want.

A third option (i.m.o. the cleanest) is to use an EFS, either write the files you need on premise directly to the EFS mount which can also be mounted on-premise. This way you have the file in 1 location but accessible from multiple locations.